# Trying to get default value from the data definition class

Tags: java, oop

Please consider two classes :

**Data Definition Class :**

```
public class A {
    private int amount = 1000;

    public A(int amount){
        this.amount = amount
    }

    public int getAmount(){
        return amount ; 
    }
}
```

**Main Class :**

```
public class B {
    public static void main (String arg[]){
        A  a = new A(2000);
        System.out.println("Amount:"+a.getAmount());
    }
}
```

Since I am passing 2000 to the constructor, I am getting 2000 in the output. But I would like to keep a option of if the user doesn't specifiy any amount, it should print
the default value which is 1000 as mentioned in the private variable in data definition class.

Is there a way I can accomplish my task using the constructor?

Comment: Add another **empty** constructor `public A(){}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class A {

    private int amount;

    public A() {
        amount = 1000;
    }

    public A(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create an empty constructor

```
public A(){

}
```

And in your `main` you will be able to do this:

```
A  a = new A();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide default constructor along with the one argument constructor you mentioned. This way user don't have to pass the amount if he don't want to while creating the object.

Comment: The developer can only provide a non-argument constructor, not a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty constructor

```
public class A {
    private int amount = 1000;

    public A(){
    }

    public A(int amount){
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getAmount(){
        return this.amount; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `public A(int amount = 1000)` ... what?

Comment: @Tom - Ha. Apologies. That was C#. Edited